# forEach solution to replace bulk code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple HTML elements on the same page and I only want to show a specified 3 elements at a time. Below, I have some code that I got to work. But I have 2 functions for each button and 9 buttons. So I have been trying to figure out what I can do to reduce the bulk. By my estimate it would be 1008 lines of code for this table of contents of 9 buttons.

```
    function clickInfoCampfer() {
  var x = document.getElementById("campferfullcard1");
  
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
} 
    function clickInfoCampferClose() {
  var x = document.getElementById("pinefullcard1");
  
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";

  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

This was my best attempt using forEach. It returns an error saying "opencard.forEach is not a function." The first part of the function is working and manages to close all the elements.

```
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.table-of-contents-college-all label');
    const allwoodcards = document.querySelectorAll('.all-wood-cards'); 

    squares.forEach(square => {
    square.addEventListener('click', clickOutcome)
    })

    function clickOutcome() {
    const opencards = this.getAttribute("opencard");
               //opencard=".full-card-campfer"//
    allwoodcards.forEach(woodcard => {
    woodcard.style.display = "none"
    });
    opencards.forEach(openup => {
        openup.style.display = "block";
    });
    
    }
```

Thanks for your thoughts.

***Edit***
HTML was requested. This HTML is supporting the forEach Java I have above. It was altered slightly from supporting the first HTML I had. There are many more div elements, I just included Pine and Campfer as the examples.

```
<body>
   <div class="tableofcontentscollege1 table-of-contents-college-all">
            <label  type="button" 
                    id="campfer-table-button"
                    opencard=".full-card-campfer"
                    >
                    Campfer
            </label>
            <label  type="button"
                    opencard=".full-card-pine"
                    >
                    Pine
            </label>
   </div>
   <div class="full-card-campfer all-wood-cards"
        id="campferfullcard1">
   </div>
   <div class="full-card-campfer all-wood-cards"
        id="campferfullcard2">
   </div>
   <div class="full-card-campfer all-wood-cards"
        id="campferfullcard3">
   </div>
   <div class="full-card-pine all-wood-cards"
        id="pinefullcard1">
   <div class="full-card-pine all-wood-cards"
        id="pinefullcard2">
   <div class="full-card-pine all-wood-cards"
        id="pinefullcard3">
   </div>
</body>
```

The goal here is to open the 3 div elements related (in name only) to the button, while closing any other div elements amongst the wood list.

Campfer button opens the 3 divs for the campfer information
Pine button opens the 3 divs for the pine information
Walnut button opens the 3 divs for the walnut information
and so on.

Hopefully that clears up any confusion.

Comment: `opencards` is a string, not an array.

Comment: It's hard to guess what you want to do without the HTML. Can you please provide it so as to have a reproducible example. Maybe `document.querySelectorAll(opencards).forEach(openup => openup.style.display = "block");` ?

Comment: I have added additional information including some of the HTML which relates.

I tried inserting that line you left me Tom. It worked perfectly.

I'm assuming this is because this line made it an array instead of what I did which had made it a string. Is that right? (referencing what Spectric said.)

Answer (score 1):

*I'm just guessing what you want. In the future, supply more context such as the effect you intend, your HTML, etc.*
You just need to put the code you had repeated in the event listener:

```js
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.table-of-contents-college-all label');

squares.forEach(square => {
    square.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
})

function handleClick() {
    if (this.style.display === "block") {
        this.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        this.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: The button is not meant to open/close itself, but rather to open/close 3 other elements. I will play around with "this" as a concept to see if I can solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Tom's answer in a comment above solved the issue for me. I supplied additional context and code in an edit to my post in case someone looks this post up for help in the future. I hope it's clear enough now. Let me know if I need to add more.